# fancybox и slick

Tags: jquery, fancybox, slick.js

Встроен слайдер slick в fancybox. Если закрыть попап окно и снова его открыть без перезагрузки страницы - пропадает кнопка закрытия этого окна и на esc также не закрывается. [link](http://atomr-web.github.io/lamar/)
Раздел "products" блок "knife"

```
$('.popup').fancybox({
    beforeShow: function() {
        $('#product__slider').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false,
            dots: true,
        });
    },
});
```

Если вызывать функцию слайдера вне fancybox, то первый слайд отображается некорректно.

Comment: У вас там `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null` при повторном открытии. Для полноценного дебага подключите полную версию файла плагина.

Comment: @br3t подключил. Проверьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Надо ковырять механизм работы `fancybox`. Похоже, при  клике на элемент он кэширует содержимое окна, а при повторном клике - отображает из кэша. И ошибка очень похожа на описанное здесь https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1953 (тоже связано с повторном вызове на элементе)

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы вы могли выделить из кода сайта минимально необходимый для воспроизведения ошибки кусочек.

Comment: @br3t да, конечно, сейчас залью на jsfiddle

Comment: @br3t почему то не получается скопировать на jsfiddle, не срабатывает попап. Если вам не сложно, посмотрите, пожалуйста, архив с версткой. Буду очень благодарен https://yadi.sk/d/sB-9oA303DQsEH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих копаний пришел к такому решению. Перед тем, как откроется попап-окно fancybox'a слайдер должен проинициализироваться. Поможет в этом коллбэк **beforeShow**.

```
$('.popup').fancybox({
    beforeShow: function() {
        $('#product__slider').slick('setPosition');
    },
});

$('#product__slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: false,
   dots: true,
   infinite: true,
   centerMode: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда закрываете попап, вам нужно удалять классы slick'а (`slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted`) с помощью `removeClass` у контейнера слайдов `#product__slider`.

Comment: Использовал коллбэк, который предложен в офф документации к fancybox'у `afterClose`, получилось вот так: `afterClose: function() {
         $('#product__slider').removeClass('slick-slider slick-initialized slick-dotted');
        }`. В итоге - закрывать могу, но элементы слайдера ведут себя не правильно. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновил гитхаб